# Different results between windows and Linux in opencv c++

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I have tried this opencv and ffmpeg C++ code to demux a video and edit it and mux it back again but it doesn't seem to work properly on windows (using Visual Studio)

the problem occurs by skipping some frames especially at the end of the video and increasing the video output size **not on all windows PCs**. We have tried it on a 35 MB video and when we did the editing the output video size was 2.8GB on some windows PCs and the last frames skipped (the problem) and some other PCs the output video size was 500MB and there were no skipped frames (all fine).

**so the question is**, why would the same code with the same build and windows versions behave differently and produce problems on some Pcs?

(we also did it on linux ubuntu and macos and it was working fine on different PCs)

https://github.com/WajdiMuh/parallelalgo for the files

https://gjuedujo-my.sharepoint.com/personal/m_albizreh1_gju_edu_jo/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Fm%5Falbizreh1%5Fgju%5Fedu%5Fjo%2FDocuments%2FParallel%20Project%2Fbinr&originalPath=aHR0cHM6Ly9nanVlZHVqby1teS5zaGFyZXBvaW50LmNvbS86ZjovZy9wZXJzb25hbC9tX2FsYml6cmVoMV9nanVfZWR1X2pvL0VzaHFWNDJCVThkQ25KOFV0dm82NHJNQmdoOWdCeEZOblkwQWtRMkQ0MU5UV3c_cnRpbWU9TTl4Zi1YblAxMGc for the release version (vidd.MP4 is the video)

Thanks in Advance